# How can I call 'atr' with arguments (input float) in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to call atr with arguments (input float) in pine version 4 but it is giving compiler error as follows.

Cannot call 'atr' with arguments (input float); available overloads: atr(integer)=>series[float];

Answer (score 0):

ATR work with Integers and plotting works with floats.
Try adding int(input) in your plot.
Integers are whole Numbers and Floats are Numbers with decimals

Comment: thanks for the answer brother, plz write the code if possible.